# Codeigniter set_value not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I'm querying the DB and sending sending a $data array from my controller to my view, where I'm using CI's form helper with set_value(field_name, default) but the data is not being loaded.

This is what I'm currently doing in my view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="artist-id" name="record_artist_id" value="<?php echo set_value('record_artist_id', $record_artist_id); ?>">
```

I thought I had to use the input helper so I tried:

```
<label for="record-name"><span class="required">*</span>Name:</label>
                    <?php
                    echo form_input([
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'name' => 'record_name',
                        'id' => 'record-name' ,
                        'class' => 'form-control',
                        'value' => set_value('record_name')
                    ]);
                    ?>
```

But still not working.

This is working though:

```
<input id="record-name" name="record_name" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($record_name)) ? $record_name : ''; ?>" class="form-control">
```

The form helper is being loaded in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file', 'form', 'base');
```

I don't know if this is related but I'm getting the view as a string and then passing it to a template, something like:

```
public function add_content($view, $content = NULL){
        $this->content = $this->load->view($view, $content, TRUE);
        return $this->content;
    }
```

and later on in a different method:

```
// render content
            $this->load->view('partials/content', ['content' => $this->content]);
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
error_reporting(1);
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

     public function test()
    {
          $this->load->helper('form','url');
          $this->load->library("form_validation");
//          echo "vijay";
          $post=$this->input->post();
          if($post)
          {
//               echo "<pre>";print_r($post);die;
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('record_name', 'Record Name', 'trim|required');
               $this->form_validation->set_rules('quantity', 'quantity Name', 'trim|required|numeric');
               if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
               {
                    redirect('/');
                    return 0;
               }
          }

          $data['message']=  validation_errors();
        $this->load->view('test',$data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>


     </head>
     <body>

          <div id="container">
               <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

               <div id="body">

               </div>
               <p>
                 <?= !empty($message) ? $message : '' ?>
               </p>
               <form method="post">
                    <label for="record-name"><span class="required">*</span>Name:</label>
                    <?php
                    $record_name_input = array('type' => 'text',
                                             'name' => 'record_name',
                                             'id' => 'record-name',
                                             'class' => 'form-control',
                                             'value' => set_value('record_name')
                    );
                    echo form_input($record_name_input);
                    ?>

                    <h5>Username</h5>
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo set_value('quantity', '0'); ?>" size="50" />
                    <?php
                    echo form_submit("submit", "submit data");
                    ?>

               </form>
          </div>

     </body>
</html>
```

> Until you won't use `$this->form_validation->run()` til that `set_value('field_name')` won't work

Comment: I got no error at all, the field is not setting the value, an empty value is being set. I check the data array before sending it to the view and it has values. If I use <input id="record-name" name="record_name" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($record_name)) ? $record_name : ''; ?>" class="form-control"> it'll work

Comment: @johansebasb check the answer again i chagned

Comment: @johansebasb `$this->form_validation->set_value('record_name');` it will give value only on when you post value and came to this page only without reloading page then only it will saw the value

Comment: That's exactly what I had before and it was working, but I also need it to work when there's data in the post in order to hold values when validating. I do understand your point but then I'm again back to square one. What would be then the correct way to use set_value()?

Comment: @johansebasb  can you edit your questions and send view and controller so i can check where you made mistakes